# CAN PIG FILTER BY COMPARING A LINE WITH OTHER LINES?

Tags: apache-pig

This is a pig latin question. My data has 3 fields as follows:

usrid      time       distance

020204       09:23:45   350.1103

020204       09:29:48   350.1522

222292       14:01:34   1.992134

I want to delete a line, if there is another line with the same usrid, such that the time gap between the 2 lines is less than 10 minutes. For example line 2 must be deleted, because line 1 has the same usrid and the time gap between the 2 is only ~6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this,

[Pig de-duplicate events occuring within 1 minute of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676921/pig-de-duplicate-events-occuring-within-1-minute-of-each-other)

The same requirement. Sliding time window. Possible solution/suggestion is there in the question